# How to add set featured image button in wp_editor()?

Tags: wp-editor

I am working in a plugin and in that plugin adding wordpress default editor(wp_editor)and adding functionality to save post with add media features.

Add media features is working absolutely fine and adding media to respective post, but i want to add image as a thumbnail but i am not able to add set featured image button to the add media button.

This is the code i am writing to add WordPress default editor:

```
wp_editor( $post_content , 'productinfoeditor', array(
'media_uploads'=>true,
'textarea_name' => 'product_info_content', 
'editor_class' => 'requiredField', 
'teeny' => true, 
'textarea_rows' => 14
) );
```

In `function.php` file

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array('post','page', 'product' ) );
```

And saving post with:

```
$post = array();
$post['post_type'] = 'product';
$post['post_content'] = $product_info_content;
$post['post_author'] = $user_ID;
$post['post_status'] = 'publish';
$post['post_title'] = $product_title;
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `product` post type should have support for `thumbnail`. [See the codex for more info on `supports`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments).